# socket_io_client listener is called twice

Tags: socket.io, dart, flutter

So I have my listeners on `initState`...

```
socket.on('synchronizedata', (packet) {
      print('packet of type ${packet['packetKind']}!-> $packet');

      _syncMessages(context, _message);
    });
```

but when the server emits `synchronizedata`, the code above is fired twice. Any thoughts? Initially, I have them on the `build` method, but after reading [issue #15], I placed them into `initState`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is your `socket` object created?

Comment: @TomAlabaster `IO.socket` created at `initState`